# Bluebird / Typescript Error: 'this' context of is not assignable to method's 'this'

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, this, bluebird

I have a series of methods (some asynchronous and some not) that I would like to use [`bluebird.each`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html) to process in order. Here is a dumbed down example:

```
import bluebird from 'bluebird';

const delay = (ms: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
class Template {
  propertyA!: number;
  propertyB!: number;
  constructor() {}
  async methodA() {
    this.propertyA = 10;
    console.log({ thisArgInA: this, propertyA: this.propertyA });
    await delay(500);
    return this.propertyA;
  }
  methodB() {
    this.propertyB = this.propertyA * 100;
    console.log({ thisArgInB: this, propertyB: this.propertyB });
    return this.propertyB;
  }
}

const instance = new Template();

const sequence = [instance.methodA, instance.methodB];

(async function main() {
  await bluebird.each(sequence, (fn) => {
    const result = fn.call(instance);
    console.log({ result });
  });
})();
```

This produces this error I do not understand:

```
index.ts:27:20 - error TS2684: The 'this' context of type '(() => Promise<number>) | (() => number)' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type '(this: Template) => Promise<number>'.
  Type '() => number' is not assignable to type '(this: Template) => Promise<number>'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Promise<number>'.

27     const result = fn.call(instance);
```

I thought maybe it is because `bluebird.each` accepts either values or promise that resolve to values the compiler can't reconcile things, but the only solution I thought of there was to strongly type the return values"

```
async methodA: Promise<number> { /*...*/ }
methodB: number { /*...*/ }
```

But that didn't change anything. Also I note the following:

- I have to provide context here, because invoking the functions in the `each` callbacks loses connection to the `Template` as `this`
- When `methodA` is synchronous (remove the `async` keyword, remove the `delay()`, just return `this.propertyA`, this works fine.
- When I remove the `return` statements things work fine.
- When I change `fn.call(instance)` to `fn.bind(instance)()` it works fine

#### How can I satisfy the compiler so it knows how to call these functions with the provided context.

Is there an easier way to call these methods in sequence so their connection to `this` is maintained?

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-wwywkc?file=index.ts)

Comment: Question: why are you using bluebird at all? It made sense back when Promises weren't a real thing yet, but [the `Promise` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) has been part of the spec for years now. Just use that, and remove a legacy dependency from your codebase? Especially given that `async` makes functions return a standard Promise without you having to write the promise code explicitly. Which you can then handle with `await` _as if_ you're writing synchronous code, without needing the promise `then().catch()` syntax.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on the StackBlitz you provided. Running `tsc` does not output any errors.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans So just remove bluebird and process the functions in `sequence` in a for-of loop would be a better solution?

Comment: @Bergi I think you'd have to run `npx ts-node index.ts`. I'm not sure if you can do global installs like tsc in that environment.

Comment: The error can be reproduced without bluebird on typescript playground though

Comment: @Bergi Can you show me what you mean with that last comment?

Comment: @1252748 https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmBbADuALvaBvAsAKGmkgE8A7YaReNACwHsATAQQAoBKbfQwgJ2oFcepaAEYADAG4u0AL7SqtRgCF2nAtz5pBwgKyTpcvIfzA6pCGmgBLc2jDlMAXmil4AdzhJUYDOyl4TMwtoCHgAR354B2hnAG0bC3tgeAA6BXpmABprWyTU9OUAXX98UIio5LSwZBYWADNSDkcAPjVCBpTgMBAQFgS7BzZ-GSGgA

Comment: @Bergi thanks, yep I got that too when I tried to change the implementation to just async/await+for-of

Answer (score 0):

It may help to look at the inferred types:

- `sequence`: `(((this: Template) => number) | ((this: Template) => Promise<number>))[]` or just `((() => Promise<number>) | (() => number))[]`
- `fn`: `((this: Template) => number) | ((this: Template) => Promise<number>)` or just `(() => Promise<number>) | (() => number)`
- `.call`: `<Template, [], number>(this: (this: Template) => number, thisArg: Template): number`

and we can see that the type of the `.call()` expression is not what we expect - the compiler wants a function returning a `number`, and complains since `fn` can alternatively return a `Promise<number>`. This is probably due to a TypeScript bug when dealing with inferring the return type of function union types. It might be related to the [subtle difference between `X => A | B` and `(X => A) | (X => B)`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44440#issuecomment-855016204).

We can fix this by writing

- `const result = fn.call<Template,[],number|Promise<number>>(instance);` or
- `…(fn: () => number | Promise<number>)) => …` or
- `const sequence`: `(() => number | Promise<number>)[]`

Comment: What are the second two type arguments to `call`? I get `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 3.` when I try that.

Comment: @1252748 They appear to be the arguments and return types of the function to be called. [It works for me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmBbADuALvaBvAsAKGmkgE8A7YaReNACwHsATAQQAoBKbfQwgJ2oFcepaAEYADAG4u0AL7SqtRgCF2nAtz5pBwgKyTpcvIfzA6pCGmgBLc2jDlMAXmil4AdzhJUYDOyl4TMwtoCHgAR354B2hnAG0bC3tgeAA6BXpmABprWyTU9OUAXX98UIio5LSwZBYWADNSDkcAPjVCBpTgMBAQAB4EFHR4TNjCzNJ+RAAjeB4AHwAFHjpEK1DeienZ5uaWBLsHNn8ZI6A).